# SSS_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED on CSV import

Tags: csv, netsuite, suitescript

This is in a Netsuite environment, using a User Event Script in Before Submit, on a CSV import that has a LOT of similar User Event script

As title, I'm getting this error on specifc large CSV file. What's interesting is that the Execution Time is 0.00s and the Script Usage is also 0. I was wondering if a different script could have triggered the error, then passed the error to all other user event scripts that operate on CSV's?

TLDR; If X number of scripts are set to operate on a record, and the first one errors out, do the others get the error?

Comment: Go to Customizations > Scripts > Scripted Records and see all scripts that are deployed to that record type you are performing a CSV import for and for each of those scripts look at the script execution log. You should see the usage limit error in whichever script is causing your issue. Once you have located the script that is causing the issue, please share what you can.